# XSLT - add new node analyzing text() node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I've a xml like follows,

```
<doc>
  <chap>&lt;The root&gt;
     &lt;element that&gt;
     &lt;declares&gt;
     &lt;the document to be an XSL style sheet&gt;</chap>
</doc>
```

I need to write xsl to add separate nodes named `<p>` to text where exist between `&lt;` and `&gt;`within `<chap>`.

So the output should be,

```
<doc>
  <p>&lt;The root&gt;</p>
  <p>&lt;element that&gt;</p>
  <p>&lt;declares&gt;</p>
  <p>&lt;the document to be an XSL style sheet&gt;</p>
</doc>
```

I can write a template to the text inside `<chap>` node like, `<xsl:template match="chap/text()"` but I cannot think of a way to add new `<p>` by analyzing the text() node within `<chap>`

Any suggestions how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you can use the `analyze-string` element, to get the text that matches the regular expression

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="&lt;(.*)&gt;">
```

And to output the text matched by the parenthesis, use `regex-group`

```
<xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)" />
```

Try this XSLT template

```
<xsl:template match="chap">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="&lt;(.*)&gt;">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <p><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)" /></p>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

Read up on Regular Expression Matching at http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/06/04/tr.html

Comment: @sanjay, instead of `<xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)" />` use `<xsl:value-of select="." />`, then you get the matched string. You can also simplify the `regex` to `&lt;.*&gt;`

Comment: I think the regex might need to be `&lt;([^&gt;]*&gt;` to avoid greedy matching.

Answer (score 1):

Check this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="chap/text()" name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="separator" select="'&gt;'"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,$separator)">
            <p>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>&gt;
            </p>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```